# How can I hide the header based on the gclid parameter?

Tags: css, parameters, parameter-passing, footer, google-ads-api

I want to hide the header and the footer only from the visitors that come from google ads(adwords) and have the gclid paramenter. How can I do that? 
Example: url with the gclid paramenter, where every parameter is unique
www.example.com/?gclid=12345abcde

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('gclid') > 0) {
    document.getElementById('header').style.display = "none"
}
```

Explanation: `window.location.href` gets the current URL, then using indexOf you can determine if a string has a given substring, if it does it returns the index, if not it returns `-1`; hence the `> 0` condition on the if statement.

Comment: Example:
to hide it from here www.example.com/?gclid=12345abcde

Comment: I'm not able to test out my idea currently. but I will be able to shortly. I will inform you if it works.

Comment: I've changed my answer after taking a look at the issue.

Comment: I've added this

<script>
if (window.location.href.indexOf('gclid') > 0 {
    document.getElementById('site-header').style.display = "none"
}
</script>
 
and I tried with a random value for the gclid parameter but the header is still showing. Here's the link https://notariate.ro/gclid/?gclid=1234

Comment: You're missing the closing bracket on the if condition, try this. `if (window.location.href.indexOf('gclid') > 0) { document.getElementById('site-header').style.display = "none" }`

Comment: I realise the error was in the example I gave - apologies for that.

Comment: Yes, it worked. Can you please tell me how can I hide the footer as well? Thanks

Comment: Just add another `document.getElementById('footer-name").style.display = "none"` inside the if statement underneath the header line. Replace `footer-name` with whatever the id you have used for the element you would like to use.

Comment: It seems it was working only on the test page. I don't why, maybe because the page had gclid in the url. I've renamed the test page https://notariate.ro/test/?gclid=sdmjh5 and it's not working anymore. You can see the code in the source code.

Comment: Can you tell me what line of code and the file where the JS snippet is? I'll be able to provide more assistance that way.

Comment: Scrap that - I found it. I believe it's because the script is being run before the content is rendered on the page. Try changing your `script` tag to the following `<script defer>`. It waits until the page is before running the script.

Comment: I've updated the script as so '<script defer>
if (window.location.href.indexOf('gclid') > 0) {
    document.getElementById('site-header').style.display = "none"
    document.getElementById('footer').style.display = "none"
}
</script>' but still didn't work. But you mentioned the script was being run before the content so I moved it's location from header to footer and now it works. Thank you very much

Comment: Do you know how can I hide be class instead of id? I've tried     `document.getElementsByClassName('elementor-location-header').style.display = "none"` but it doesn't work.
I've changed the header and footer and I can only see their classes https://notariate.ro/test/

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array of elements, not a single instance. So you would either have to specify, such as `document.getElementsByClassName('elementor-location-header').style.display = "none"` or iterate over the array to apply it to all elements.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('elementor-location-header').style.display = "none"` does not work. How can I hide the elementor-location-header class?

Comment: `<div data-elementor-type="header" data-elementor-id="2425" class="elementor elementor-2425 elementor-location-header" data-elementor-settings="[]">` here's the whole for the header from https://notariate.ro/test/?gclid=sdmjh5